# Why did Rihanna put out a tweet in support of the farmer's protests in India?

Tags: political-system

Why did [Riri ( Rihanna)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rihanna) put out a tweet in support of farmers in India ?

[Kangana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangana_Ranaut) - Bollywood queen - said in response that Rihanna was funded by Khalistan, so she tweeted.

Is this true?

Comment: I'm afraid that questions about the internal motivations of people are off-topic here. The only person who knows for sure why Rihanna made that tweet is Rihanna herself.

Comment: Even if we could answer questions about her internal motivations not knowing what was tweeted makes it impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Because she supports them?

Comment: For questions that amount to "is this published statement true?", you should check out [skeptics.se]. I'm not sure if this question would be on-topic there either, but it's a closer fit than here

Comment: @F1Krazy: So why has the BBC been able to work out why?

Comment: I don't think Rihanna needs to take money from Sikh separatist movements. She's got like 600 million dollars.

Comment: @divibisan: Why "Skeptics", the question is all about the politics of protest and is spot on for this site.

Comment: @MoziburUllah The question is claiming that Rihanna tweeted about the protests because she was paid to tweet about them, not because she genuinely supports them. Such a claim (backed up by a source) belongs on Skeptics as divibisan suggested, not here.

Comment: @F1Krazy: That's not his first question, that's a later assertion and one that the BBC reported on too. Obvious nonsense of course: the Bollywood actress mentioned the word "terrorist" (the talking point of all rightwing nuts ever since the US war on terrorism) and obviously way out of touch in the Bolly bubble  high above the concerns of tte common people. Her bubble needs pricking, in my opinion.

Comment: It would be churlish of me to list all of the questions, answers, and comments written by a certain someone that mention the word "terrorist," of course.

Comment: @ouflak Please stay away from grammar and wording edits in future if the question is unsalvageable. It just puts it in the question back on the queue and makes for extra review tasks. (It should have been auto-deleted but alas, it got a positive-score answer.)

Comment: @Jan, I agree. Was surprised it wasn't deleted until I noticed that answer. I'll restrain myself in the future. I.... promise....

Comment: https://www.news18.com/news/india/rihanna-was-paid-2-5-million-by-pr-firm-with-khalistani-links-to-tweet-in-support-of-farmers-report-3394502.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rihanna's tweet has been [reported](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.bbc.co.uk/news/amp/world-asia-india-55914858) by the BBC and is said by them to have angered Modi's government. She's tweeting in support of farmers protests against new pro-corporate farming laws. These protests have swept all over India. There have been violent clashes and some protestors have occupied the red fort and they have camped just outside Delhi's borders. The government has suspended internet service in three regions of Delhi. I think Rihanna's intentions are pretty clear: she supports their protest. Good for her.

In fact, the farmers protests have been ongoing since early December last year and coincided with a call for a general strike. An estimated 250 million people have been out on the streets protesting with images of tractors breaking down police barricades and one protestor has said on live national tv to a reporter, "this is a revolution, sir".

Comment: It's disputed that these new farming laws are 'pro-corporate'. Depending on how the laws are implemented and how the farmers decide to take advantage of those laws, it could go either way. Though I do agree that if the farmers do manage to successfully utilize these laws to their own advantage and to the disadvantage of ever growing corporate profits, then it won't be long before you see some 'amendments' to these laws introduced, or some new laws altogether put forward.